# IaC Deployment in Azure with Terraform + Chef vs. Puppet vs. Ansible for Data Engineers

Tags: ansible, terraform, chef, infrastructure-as-code, puppet

I am an *Azure Data Engineer* and try to leverage the IaC benefits in this area of *Azure Data Factory, Azure Databricks, Azure SQL & Synapse, Azure Power BI, Azure IoT*.
After some research I figured out that I need two essential parts:

```
1.Provisioning part
2.Configuration management part
```

Breaking down to technology I decided to use *Terraform* for the provisioning of infrastructure like (RG, Network, DBs etc).
For the configuration management I am still not sure what to choose between *Chef, Puppet and Ansible*.
There is another idea to use *Docker/Packer* + *Kubernetes*.

What are the best practices of IaC and automation when it comes to the Area of Data Engineering/Big Data?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud setup could be done completly by Terraform. Check out terraform provider resources for required parameters ex. [Azure Data Factory](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory)

Configuration management stuff mostly in use for OS tuning inside Virtual Machines. So maybe you don't need them at all.